# environment variables in redirectors, perfecting my log scripts

Tags: linux, redirect

The following command, run either from cron or the prompt, does not make the expected log. I expect to get a log with the date as the file name. I am able to do this in Windows by using `%date%` and it makes the date the filename. What am I doing wrong here.

```
/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/test.sh>/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/$date.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/test.sh > "/root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/$(date).log" 2>&1
```

Comment: I get: "-bash: /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/$(date).log: ambiguous redirect"

Comment: Oops, I added the "", try now :P

Comment: Wonderful! That's it. That makes for a rather large filename, but it works. Thank you.